# BibTeX will not compile

Tags: macos, latex, bibtex, tex

I am trying to compile a bibliography that is externally linked but I get back an error saying

> I couldn't open file name `firstbibtex.aux`

Here is the referencing code:

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ( {CTAN} )",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittleback and Alexander Smarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

Here is the tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    hello world!\cite{greenwade93} and then someone said good night world! \cite{goossens93}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{firstbibtex}

\end{document}
```

This is based on this [tutorial](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/bibliographies).

The names of the files are firstindex.bib and untitled.tex(note: the .tex is not fliename)

They have been complied using the pdftex and TEX and DVI via TexShop on mac. They have also been complied using the following on the command line

```
latex firstindex 
bibtex firstindex
latex firstindex
latex firstindex
```

Comment: How are your files named? Please [edit] and add this to the question. Also, which files are currently in your folder? Which tools are you using to compile? Or which commands are you using?

Comment: Have you compiled the document before running bibtex so that there exists an .aux file?

Comment: N.N: yes it was complied before 
slhck: hope this helps 

thank you both for your reply. sorry about my late reply

Comment: You need to mention users with @slhck to have them get a notification.

Comment: @slhck >) thanks for that. didn't know that they added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The names of the files are firstindex.bib and untitled.tex

Then that's where your problem is. The name of the bibliography file. `firstbibtex.bib` is *only* used internally and since it is referenced from your `.tex` file already, you don't need to specify it anymore.

If your file is called `untitled.tex`, you need to typeset it with:

```
latex untitled.tex
```

This will create the auxfile needed for BibTeX, called `untitled.aux`. It tells BibTeX where to look for the references (there should be something like `\bibdata{firstbibtex}` in it). Then you can call:

```
bibtex untitled.aux
```

Then, typeset the document again:

```
latex untitled.tex
latex untitled.tex
```

And you're done.